# getActionCommand with .equal not equaling properly

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm trying to learn Jtextfields and action listeners. I was following this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-swing-jtextfield/, but I'm encountering an error with this function.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String input = e.getActionCommand();
    if (input.equals("submit")) {
        displaysText.setText(textField.getText());
        textField.setText("");
        System.out.println("Entered if statement");
    }
}
```

No matter what I input into the text field it will enter that if statement. It should just enter that if statement when I enter "submit". Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

If it's any help here is all of the code

```
package IncludesMain;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    static JTextField textField;
    static JFrame frame;
    static JButton button;
    static JLabel displaysText;
    Main() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frame = new JFrame("textfield");
        displaysText = new JLabel("N/A");
        button = new JButton("submit");

        Main textObject = new Main();
        button.addActionListener(textObject);
        textField = new JTextField(16);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(textField);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(displaysText);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.show();


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String input = e.getActionCommand();
        if (input.equals("submit")) {
            displaysText.setText(textField.getText());
            textField.setText("");
            System.out.println("Entered if statement");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The getActionCommand method gets the action command String from the JButton.  If you need to test the JTextField text input that text would be textField.getText();.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `e.getActionCommand()` is taking the actionCommand of the button, because you are putting the listener on there. You need to set the listener on the textfield

Instead of

```
Main textObject = new Main();
button.addActionListener(textObject);
textField = new JTextField(16);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

It should be

```
Example textObject = new Example();
textField = new JTextField(16);
textField.addActionListener(textObject);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

Also if you do this then you must press Enter to submit the value, the button won't work unless you refactor the logic inside the actionPerformed method